# give folder read permission when create directory using laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

I have a case suppose I upload an image for a product to a temporary directory called "uploads" and then later move it to another one called "products" and the image will be in a sub-directory which created dynamically like this

```
products/1/variants/1/image.jpeg
```

1. "products" is the main directory have permission 0755 which is accessible
2. "/1/variants/1/" dynamically created directory have permission 0700 which is not accessible and can't read the image

my code of moving

```
$sourcePath = 'public/'.$image['path'];
$destinationPath = "products/".$product>id."/variants/".$variantImages['variantId']."/".pathinfo($sourcePath, PATHINFO_BASENAME);


Storage::makeDirectory("public/images/products/".$product->id."/variants/".$variantImages['variantId']);

Storage::move($sourcePath, "public/images/".$destinationPath);
```

notice : I use Hostinger hosting

image moved to the right directory but i can't read because of the permission

I expect to read the image

1. storage:link (symbolic link) is correct
2. filesystem config for storage disk is correct and set to 0755
3. I also tried to use storage visibility `Storage::setVisibility()`
4. when using Storage::makeDirectory($dir, 0755, true)

Comment: This looks like a pretty unsafe way of doing this. also with a lot of redundancy. I am not sure why you are attempting to do it that way.

Comment: Need more information. This example is very confusing.

Comment: What is the error code. I think I know you problem. Also what version of laravel are you running.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is move images from the storage path to the public folder.

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents, 'public');
```

I think this is more the approach you should go. Either that or change the visibility if you want it persisted.

```
$visibility = Storage::getVisibility('file.jpg');
 
Storage::setVisibility('file.jpg', 'public');
```

the public folder being accessible and then you can add the path you would like it to be found in. Same goes for the put.

if not and you are truly wanting to do what you are doing above and fix it. You have an error in question where you have "$product>id" and it should be "$product->id"

I think after your comment you will know more about the issue when doing this.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 
$variantId = $variant['variantId'];
$productId = $product->id;

// Manually specify a filename...
$path = Storage::putFileAs("images/products/$productId/variants/$variantId" , new File($sourcePath), pathinfo($sourcePath, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

dump($path);

$file = File::get($path);

dd($file);
```

also ensure you filesystem config is set properly

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'permissions' => [
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0644,
            'private' => 0600,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0755,
            'private' => 0700,
        ],
    ],
],
```

I retrieved references for this from laravel documentation seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility)

Comment: At first sorry for this "$product>id" in my code actually I wrote it like "$product->id"
No I'm not "I think what you are trying to do is move images from the storage path to the public folder."

I try to move from storage path called "uploads" to another one the storage path called "products" but I will not put it directly inside products it has to create sub-directory inside products first.
When I do that I can't read images in sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your user/group of your webserver, hopefully you have access to `ssh` and make necessary change.

```bash
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data -R storage/path
$ sudo chmod 755 -r storage/path
```

now you should be able to read the created image.